# What is the difference between charming girl and girl charming?

Tags: articles, word-order

I saw the sentence on the internet like 'I thought my rescuer would be prince charming'.

I think 'I thought my rescuer would be a charming prince' is also right.
Why does he obstinately use the sentence like 'I thought my rescuer would be prince charming' instead of 'I thought my rescuer would be a charming prince'
I want to know the difference in meaning.

[image]

And one more thing, why does the writer omitted 'a' in front of prince in the sentence 'I thought my rescuer would be prince charming'.

Comment: Please try to always include *real* examples with actual context when you post your questions.  Before your edit, this was a very low quality question and unanswerable.  After your edit, it became a good question and a worthy contribution to the site.  Would you rather ask low-quality and unanswerable questions, or would you rather get useful answers?

Answer (score 4):

When the adjective/modifier follows a noun in this way, the modifier often identifies an  iconic type of the noun or an established role of the noun:

> knight errant
>
> prince charming
>
> lion rampant, stag trippant
>
> president *pro tem*
>
> Surgeon General
>
> bar sinister
>
> heirs male
>
> heir apparent, heir presumptive
>
> forest primeval
>
> trout almondine

Answer (score 2):

> [Prince Charming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Charming)

is a moniker from fairytales who rescues damsels in distress.

He is also usually portrayed as a

> charming prince

A similar phrase for females might be

> sleeping beauty

Comment: thanks, but why do the writer a moniker in small letters?

Comment: Maybe because they thought it as more the generic term and not the specific character.

Comment: @박용현 The small letters are just sloppiness. It should be Prince Charming.